# View at vs Look at

Tags: word-choice

> The blog offers a behind-the-scenes `look/view` at how the research
>   was done.

Are both words inter-changeable in this situation?

Comment: No, they're not interchangeable. _Look_ needs _at_, but _view_ needs _of_.

Comment: This question needs looking at. In my view it should be on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They take different prepositions (look at, view of), but also the meaning might be just a little bit different.

For a behind-the-scenes view, the camera (so to speak) is at a bit more of a distance than for a behind-the-scenes look.

A behind-the-scenes look might be more detailed than the behind-the-scenes view.

I'm explaining this to help you choose between them.  However, don't give yourself a headache choosing between them, because there is very little difference between them.